# How do I synchronise crypto.randomBytes() function of crypto module in node js?

Tags: node.js, async-await

```
crypto = require('crypto')
async function generateToken(){
  await crypto.randomBytes(256,function(ex, buffer) {
    if (ex) {
      console.log("error generating token");
    }

        var token =  crypto
          .createHash('sha1')
          .update(buffer)
          .digest('hex');

        console.log(token);



  }
)}
console.log("before token");
generateToken();
console.log("after token");
```

In the above code, I wanted to synchronize the `generateToken()` method. So I **added `async` and `await`** to the function, but I'm not getting the expected output which is

```
before token 
7f4f27037cd7dd65bd03d7e2fe859e608b9eebe2
after token
```

the output I'm getting is

```
before token 
after token
7f4f27037cd7dd65bd03d7e2fe859e608b9eebe2
```

What am I doing wrong in the above code?

**edit:**
the following code would work but it is not synchronized.

```
crypto = require("crypto");
function generateToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buffer) {
      if (ex) {
        reject("error generating token");
      }
      const token = crypto
        .createHash("sha1")
        .update(buffer)
        .digest("hex");
      resolve(token);
    });
  });


  console.log(token);
}

console.log("before token");
generateToken().then((token) => {
  console.log(token);
  console.log("after token");
});
```

Comment: The answer below sums it up, when you call generateToken() it is not blocking so the console log statements are exactly as you'd expect.

Answer (score 7):

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
async function generateToken() {
  const buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buffer) {
      if (ex) {
        reject("error generating token");
      }
      resolve(buffer);
    });
  });
  const token = crypto
    .createHash("sha1")
    .update(buffer)
    .digest("hex");

  console.log(token);
  return token;
}

console.log("before token");
generateToken().then(token => {
  console.log("after token", token);
});
```

You can also call it in other async function

```
async function otherFunction() {
  try {
    console.log("before token");
    const token = await generateToken();
    console.log("after token", token);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the generateToken method is synchronized. I don't want to use then function here.

Comment: Where do you want to use it?

Comment: I want to be able to write somethig like this console.log("before token");
generateToken();
console.log("after token");

Comment: You can do that in other async function with await and then you can call the other function

Answer (score 7):

If you don't specify a function, then a synchronous version of the function is used and it returns the resulting bytes.

```
token = crypto.randomBytes(256)
```

That way you don't need any kind of *synchronization* (everything is a callback, even when called promises, wait, async, whatnot... so synchronous code in an asynchronous world requires each previous callback to start the next asynchronous job, which can be annoying in some simple cases like this one.)

Answer (score 2):

**this is working fine...**

```
 crypto = require("crypto");

    function generateToken() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buffer) {
          if (ex) {
            reject();
          }
          const token = crypto
            .createHash("sha1")
            .update(buffer)
            .digest("hex");
          console.log(token);
          resolve();
        });
      });

    }

    async function otherFunction() {
      try {
        console.log("before token");
        await generateToken()
        console.log("after token");
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    }
    otherFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method works with TypeScript `"typescript": "^3.4.4"`

```
const randomKey = async (length: Number) => {
  const buffer = await crypto.randomBytes(16);
  return buffer.toString("hex");
};

const getAndLogKey = async () => {
  const randomKey = await randomKey(16);
  console.log(randomKey);
};
```

should work with JS too

Comment: Keep in mind that this code will actually use the synchronous version of crypto.randomBytes. The async and await keywords can just be dropped in this example. To use the asynchronous version, you need to include a callback as a second parameter. ([Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback))